# Facebook page to share the video and then display custom text message at the end of the video

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am developing a Facebook app with Facebook API. I am looking into a feature that can share the video.

At the end of the video segment, however, I need to display a custom message.

This message will change during the course of time and will be something that the user will post on their Facebook wall.

Please advice if this is possible. If yes, then please share your thoughts. I have tried the API; however, I could not find any method in the API, which allows creating videos in run-time nor allows me to embed text to the video. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something along the lines of ffmpeg to splice into the video and something like imagemagik to create the appropriate frames.

Comment: Thanks Damian however the plugins features are limited only to extent of reading the videos file attributes and in creating thumbnail images of that video. This plugin can be used only to extent of making a video file's  thumbnail  gallery with all the videos attributes listed there in. I need the video and then embed the text at the end of the video.

Comment: You are going to have to pull the video to your server first and then edit it appropriately before performing another share/re upload. The Facebook api won't give this to you for free .